# Python Pexels API Per_page

Tags: python, api, pixel

according to [Pexels API](https://www.pexels.com/api/documentation#videos-search), you can set up a "per_page" integer | optional - The number of results you are requesting per page. Default: 15 Max: 80

So, I do:

```
video_base_url = 'https://api.pexels.com/videos/search'
my_obj_video = {'query':'fitness','width':1080,'height':1920,'per_page':80}
requesting_video = requests.get(video_base_url,headers = {'Authorization':api_key}, data = my_obj_video)
```

But when I download these videos, via f.write(requests.get), I only get 15 results, even though I set up per page being 80. Is there anything wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are using headers in requests.get, the correct is params.

```
video_base_url = 'https://api.pexels.com/videos/search'
my_obj_video = {'query':'fitness','width':1080,'height':1920,'per_page':80}
requesting_video = requests.get(video_base_url,params = {'Authorization':api_key}, data = my_obj_video)
```